# How to sort array based on key?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array which has two types of objects: Awarded and non-awarded. I simply want to sort my array so that awarded objects are placed first, and the rest are placed afterwards.

Here is the code that defines the key "awarded":

```
if let awarded = achievements[indexPath.row].userRelation["awarded"] as? String where awarded != "<null>" { }
```

Within those brackets I'd like to use my unwrapped value "awarded" to sort through the achievements and add those to the beginning, and the rest at the end.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: What exactly is an `achievement` here? Is it an object, which contains a `userRelation` dictionary <String, String>? Kind of a strange entity model :/

Comment: yeah it contains a bunch of properties, one of which is userRelation which has the "awarded" key

Comment: var descriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "awarded", ascending: false)
var stories = (achievements as NSArray).sortedArray(usingDescriptors: [descriptor])

Answer (score 2):

You should experiment with `sort` function, it is very useful.

```
let sortedAchievements = achievements.sorted{ $0.userRelation["awarded"] < $1.userRelation["awarded"] }
```

To sort in place use this:

```
achievements.sort{ $0.userRelation["awarded"] < $1.userRelation["awarded"] }
```

I would recommend to refactor your model. It's better to use objects or structs instead of dictionaries. Also `awarded` should be a `Bool` property, not a `String`, right?